# Is it possible to do responsive design with SharePoint 2013?

Tags: responsive-design, sharepoint-2013

I am not a SharePoint developer but I have done responsive design for other projects.  I need to do responsive design under SharePoint 2013.  Is it possible?  I need to stay away from adaptive design (device detection with bootstrap or zurb).  I need to do everything with media queries.  Any links to training videos, website resources, or books on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on what you are looking for, is it in this case a sharepoint app, or do you wish to change the default look to create a response design that you can assign to one or more sites? There are ways to create new masterpages that incorporate only the items you really want to show (eg: minim masterpage), or with the app, you can just start from an empty page, but request the data using an O-Data service, where you have to possibility to show it as you like (without a predefined css with many quirks)

Comment: We are completely changing the default design.  It will be a content heavy website.  There will be a master page, two landing pages, and two other detail pages.  It will be something similar to this where it looks nothing like SharePoint:  http://team.eas.com/